# Finding out my current LDAP server type

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap

How can i find out if my current LDAP sever type is Standalone, Master or Replica (slave)?

I am using OpenLDAP on SLES 11.

Comment: ...by looking at your configuration files?

Answer (score 0):

In your slapd.conf file, you can check if there is any information about syncprov (thus, your server is a Master), or syncrepl (it would be a slave), which are modules made for replication.

If you're not sure, you can have a look in the current configuration of your server, by binding yourself on cn=config, and searching in the configuration of your "hdb" or "bdb" (or wathever) database if there is one of these two modules loaded.